# How to add a c++ vector of weights to a caffe model in C++

Tags: c++, caffe

In the c++ program below how do I add the c++ vector of weights to the convolution layer?

I have a `caffe::ConvolutionParameter` obejct `convParam`, how do I add weights to it? Do I need to use a `caffe::BlobProto` object?

Do I need to loop and copy the weights in one by one?

I've searched online and cannot find any examples of how to do this in C++.

When I have this done I will write it to a caffemodel file. I am already writing the network to a prototxt file.

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h>
#include <google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.h>
#include <google/protobuf/text_format.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream> // NOLINT(readability/streams)
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "caffe.pb.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <caffe/caffe.hpp>

using namespace std;
using google::protobuf::Message;
using google::protobuf::io::CodedInputStream;
using google::protobuf::io::CodedOutputStream;
using google::protobuf::io::FileInputStream;
using google::protobuf::io::FileOutputStream;
using google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyInputStream;
using google::protobuf::io::ZeroCopyOutputStream;

/*Network object*/
caffe::NetParameter netParam; 

int main()
{
           caffe::LayerParameter *layerParam = netParam.add_layer();

            /*Set name and type of the layer*/
            layerParam->set_name("Test";
            layerParam->set_type("Convolution");

            /*Get the input operation*/
            layerParam->add_bottom("bootom");

            /*Get the output operation*/
            layerParam->add_top("top");

            /*Set layer to have a conv parameter*/
            caffe::ConvolutionParameter *convParam = layerParam->mutable_convolution_param();

            /*Set stride on ConvolutionParameter object*/
            convParam->add_stride(2);

            /*Set kernel on ConvolutionParameter object*/
            convParam->add_kernel_size(3);

            /*Set number of output channels*/
            convParam->set_num_output(64);

             /*weights*/
             vector<int> weights{ 10, 20, 30 }; 

            //How to add weights to the layer??

            //add_blobs()
            caffe::BlobProto *blobProto = layerParam->add_blobs();
            blobProto->has_shape();


            /*create prototxt*/
            std::ofstream ofs;
            ofs.open("test.prototxt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
            ofs << netParam.Utf8DebugString();
            ofs.close();

            return 0;
}
```